# How to extract python builtin function code

Tags: python, built-in, python-internals

As far as I know, python builtin functions are compiled from C source code and are built into the interpreter. Is there any way to find out where fuction code is situated to look at it in a disassembler?

**Addition:**
For such function id() returns an address, isn't it? But when I look at it in the debugger it contains something far from asm code.

**Addition 2:**
I have no source code because the interpreter is custom built.

Answer (score 4):

All built-ins are defined in the `__builtin__` module, defined by the [`Python/bltinmodule.c` source file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/24f86799e9d3/Python/bltinmodule.c).

To find a specific built-in, look at the [module initialisation function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/24f86799e9d3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2666), and the [module methods table](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/24f86799e9d3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2603), then grep the Python source code for the definition of the attached function. Most *functions* in `__builtin__` are defined in the same file.

For example the [`dir()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is found in the methods table as:

```c
{"dir",             builtin_dir,        METH_VARARGS, dir_doc},
```

and `builtin_dir` is defined [in the same file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/24f86799e9d3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l580), delegating to `PyObject_Dir()`:

```c
static PyObject *
builtin_dir(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *arg = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "dir", 0, 1, &arg))
        return NULL;
    return PyObject_Dir(arg);
}
```

A quick grep through the Python sources leads to [`Objects/object.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/24f86799e9d3/Objects/object.c#l1963), where `PyObject_Dir()` is implemented with several helper functions:

```c
/* Implementation of dir() -- if obj is NULL, returns the names in the current
   (local) scope.  Otherwise, performs introspection of the object: returns a
   sorted list of attribute names (supposedly) accessible from the object
*/
PyObject *
PyObject_Dir(PyObject *obj)
{
    PyObject * result;

    if (obj == NULL)
        /* no object -- introspect the locals */
        result = _dir_locals();
    else
        /* object -- introspect the object */
        result = _dir_object(obj);

    assert(result == NULL || PyList_Check(result));

    if (result != NULL && PyList_Sort(result) != 0) {
        /* sorting the list failed */
        Py_DECREF(result);
        result = NULL;
    }

    return result;
}
```